# Print the text from all inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I need to print all the text from inputs in the div "readyorder". So for it prints some of them but I need to print also the text from inputs which are showing up after I click on "AddAuthor". So when I click on "AddAuthor" the next three inputs are showing up and I need to print them in the same div as additional informations. It must happen to all inputs which are showing up. Can I ask for help??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>

    <input type="text" name="file-1" />
    <input type="text" name="surname-1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add author" id="add_input" />

    <form name="add_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    </form>

    <hr>

    <div id="readyorder"></div>
    <br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = Load;
        var number = 0;

        function Load() {
            document.getElementById('add_input').onclick = AddElement;
        }

        function AddElement() {
            var element1 = document.createElement('input');
            var element2 = document.createElement('input');
            var element3 = document.createElement('input');
            var label1 = document.createElement('label');
            var label2 = document.createElement('label');
            var label3 = document.createElement('label');
            var button = document.createElement('input');

            label1.innerHTML = "<br />Author's Name " + number + "<br />";

            element1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            element1.setAttribute('id', 'name' + number);
            element1.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name...');
            label1.appendChild(element1);

            label2.innerHTML = '<br /> Initial ' + number + '<br />';

            element2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            element2.setAttribute('id', 'initial' + number);
            element2.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Initial...');
            label2.appendChild(element2);

            label3.innerHTML = '<br />Surname ' + number + '<br />';

            element3.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            element3.setAttribute('id', 'surname' + number);
            element3.setAttribute('placeholder', 'surname...');
            label3.appendChild(element3);

            button.setAttribute('onclick', 'getText(' + number + ')');
            button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
            button.setAttribute('value', 'Button ' + number);

            document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label1);
            document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label2);
            document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label3);
            document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(button);
            number++;
        }

        function getText(id) {
            var name = document.getElementById("name" + id);
            var initial = document.getElementById("initial" + id);
            var surname = document.getElementById("surname" + id);
            var div = document.getElementById("readyorder")

            var wydawnictwo = document.getElementById("title");
            var rokwydania = document.getElementById("otherinfo");
            var div = document.getElementById("readyorder")
            div.innerHTML = "(" + "," + " " + "s." + " " + page.value + ")" + "(" + name.value + " " + initial.value + "," + " " + "s." + " " + surname.value + ")" + year.value;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: put a () after AddElement and check if it works.

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: you don't have a dom element with add_input id attribute. it crashes your whole javascript.

Comment: I see, how would a dom element with add_input id attribute look like?

Comment: `<input type="button" id="add_input" value="Add input">`

Comment: `<button id="add_input">lorem</button>` `<p id="add_input">ipsum</p>` `<div id='add_input'>dolor</div>` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to my code but it still does not write anything in div "readyorder". I'm sorry, maybe I didn't put it in the correct way. How would you put it to the code?

Comment: Why have you trying to use title.value when title is undefined?

Comment: You are right, I shouldn't take that. I just need to go with all authors' initials, names and surnames and then with page number and year. I just edited it, why isn't still write the text from inputs in div "readyorder"?

Comment: **sidenote:** `</br>` should be `<br />` (including the space)

Comment: Ok, I edited it. Do you know why is it still not working?

Comment: don't use setAttribute for onclick! That is what addEventListener is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')).forEach(input =>
   console.log(`INPUT of name ${input.name} has value = ${input.value}.`)
 )
```

By that, you will print all text **inputs** existing in the page.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')).forEach(input =>
       console.log(`INPUT of name ${input.name} has value = ${input.value}.`)
     )
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Agg" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Garg" />
```

Comment: Well, I need to put all informations together and show them in the div "readyorder". Do you know how can I do that?